# Not able to run apt-get command for docker image creation

Tags: docker-compose

```
I have centos Machine as a docker host and i was trying to create a container with UBUNTU
my docker compose file in docker host is as following
```

FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get install -y git && \
        apt-get clean

```
When i was trying to build the image i am getting the following error
This is the section for building the image

[root@testcent image_creation]# docker build -t ubuntu_git/venkat_ubu_git .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 3556258649b2
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get install -y git &&     apt-get clean
 ---> Running in 6b12dfaed5b8

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package git
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git &&  apt-get clean' returned a non-zero code: 100
[root@testcent image_creation]# </i>
```

$ Can any one please help  me

Answer (score 0):

Normally docker base images won't support directly installing packages without update command.  check and try out with the below if it works for you.

RUN **apt-get update &&** apt-get install -y git && apt-get clean